# Rewrite URL if page exists in a sub folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this sort of URL rewriting;

```
RewriteRule ^example-link-1?$ /blog/example-link-1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^example-link-2?$ /blog/example-link-2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^example-link-3?$ /blog/example-link-3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^example-link-4?$ /blog/example-link-4 [NC,L]
```

where you go directly to a link such as `example.com/example-link-1` and you are actually shown content from `example.com/blog/example-link-1`, but without the need for a new rule per page i add. Is there a dynamic way to do this in the htaccess? ie;

IF exists('blog/'+pageURI)
THEN rewrite to 'blog/'+pageURI but keep the uri without 'blog/' in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure you can do:

```
RewriteRule ^(example-link-[1234])/?$ /blog/$1 [NC,L]
```

for above 4 rules. But in general you can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /blog/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite to `/blog/something` if `/blog/something` exists while keeping the same URI without `/blog/`.